# Insertar registro en MYSQL y despues recargar pagina

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql

Mi duda es la siguiente, yo inserto un dato automaticamente en MYSQL desde el momento que cargo una pagina, para despues de ahi jalar ese registro a un input en HTML, pero mi problema esta en que no puedo obtener ese dato hasta que vuelva a recargar mi pagina, quisiera saber si hay alguna manera de una vez insertado el registro, recargar la pagina ahi mismo, este es el codigo que yo uso para insertar.

```
$validLines=array("Linea 01","Linea 02","Linea 03","Linea 04","Linea 05","Linea 06");
if ( in_array($linea,$validLines) ){
   $QueryLineAdd="INSERT INTO psb_smt.psb_info (linea, DateTime, EndDate)
    SELECT * FROM (SELECT '".$linea."', '".$StarDate." ".$TimeNow."', '".$EndDate." 06:39:00') AS tmp
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT DateTime, EndDate, linea FROM psb_smt.psb_info WHERE linea = '".$linea."' AND 
        DateTime >= '".$StarDate." 06:40:00' AND EndDate<='".$EndDate." 06:39:00'
    ) LIMIT 1";

    echo mysqli_query($conexion,$QueryLineAdd);
} else {
   //No se lanzará el INSERT, mostrar un mensaje o lo que quieras
}
```

Modifico:
Para ejecutar el archivo "adline.php" donde tengo la consulta anterior tengo el siguiente codigo en mi archivo donde mando la informacion.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            var datos=$('#frmpsb').serialize();
            $.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                url:"adline.php",
                data:datos,
                success:function(r){
                    if(r==1){

                    }else{
                        alert('Linea no existente.');
                        window.location='index.php';
                    }
                }
            });
    });
```

Comment: Como es una peticion ajax, deberias de despues de hacer el insert, haces un select y traes los datos, y con el echo lo recoges en el ajax y los datos los mandas al input con Jquery

Answer (score 0):

Para insertar puedes hacer algo asi en php:

```
$descripcion = "";
if(isset($_POST["descripcion"])) $descripcion  = $_POST["descripcion"];

//Inicia la conexion
$con = cnn();

//PERMITE CARACTERES ESPECIALES COMO ACENTOS, Ñ, ETC
mysqli_set_charset($con,"utf8");

$sql = "INSERT INTO datos(id, descripcion) VALUES(null, '".$descripcion."'); "; 

//
if($respuesta = mysqli_query($con, $sql)){
    $data = "0";
} else {
    $data = $sql;
}

//imprimir resultado
print $data;


//Cierra la conexion
mysqli_close($con);
```

y con ajax lo envias los datos asi:

```js
function grabar(){

var descripcion $('#descripcion').val();

  $.ajax({
     type:'POST',
     url:'grabar.php',/
     data:({descripcion:descripcion }),
     crossDomain: true,
     cache: false,
     success: function(data){ 
           if(data){

             alert('Creado correctamente!');
           } else {
              alert('Error al crear!');
           }
       }

  });

}
```